# Proof Gol means ball in Sanskrit

Tags: sanskrit

Is their proof Gol means ball or sphere in Hindu text is it used to refer to a ball a rock of sorts, or a clearly spherical object?

Comment: I believe *bhu*-*gol* is itself how *gol* turned out to be *round* and not the other way. You may check reputed Sanskrit dictionary in such case.

Comment: Saṁskṛtakośas Vācaspatyam and Śabdakalpdruma mention 'sarvavarttula' (round from everywhere) as the definition for 'golaḥ'

Comment: @Bingming cool which scripture is this verse from?